# ReactJS -- Unable to find latest title from an api causing error

Tags: reactjs

I have a Landing component and a NewsLatest component. I am hitting on an api and trying to find the article with the latest timestamp but iam unable to get it done in reactJS.I checked the js code its working fine but in react it is not rendering. Kindly suggest something.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import NewsSearch from '../NewsSearch/NewsSearch';
import NewsLatest from '../NewsLatest/NewsLatest';
import './Landing.css';
import axios from 'axios';


class Landing extends Component {
 state={
  newsList: []
 }
 componentDidMount(){
  axios.get(`https://api.nytimes.com/svc/topstories/v2/home.json?api-key=7cK9FpOnC3zgoboP2CPGR3FcznEaYCJv`)
  .then(res=> {
   this.setState({newsList: res.data.results});
  });

 }
 render() {
  // console.log(this.state.newsList);
  return (
   <div className="landing text-center text-white">
    <h1>News Portal</h1>

    <div className="news-search">
      <NewsSearch />
    </div>
     <div className="news-latest">
       <NewsLatest newsList={this.state.newsList}/>
     </div>
   </div>
  )
 }
}
export default Landing;
```

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
// import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class NewsLatest extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
             newsTitle:'',
             abstract:'',
             newsUrl:'',
            }
    // this.newsLatest = this.newsLatest.bind(this);
   }


   newsLatest = (e)=>{
    // e.preventDefault();
    const {newsList} = this.props;
    let maxTime = newsList.map(function(o) { 
       return new Date(o.updated_date);  
    });
     let maximumValue = Math.max(...maxTime);
     let latestnews = newsList.filter(function (el) {
          return maximumValue === new Date(el.updated_date).getTime();
          })[0];
     if(latestnews){
       this.setState({newsTitle: latestnews.title});
       return (<h4>{this.state.newsTitle}</h4>);
     }
   }
   newsTitle = () => (
    this.props.newsList.map(item => (<h2 key={item.title}>{item.title}</h2>))
  )
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.newsList);
    return (
      <div>
         <h2>News Latest....</h2>
         {this.newsLatest()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default NewsLatest;
```

There is some issue in rendering in NewsLatest component. KIndly suggest something.

Comment: What is the issue? What is not working? Please try making a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

You must probably be getting a maximum depth error, use a lifecycle method instead like `componentDidUpdate`. Update your component state only if the previous props are different from the newer ones.

Read more here: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
// import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class NewsLatest extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      newsTitle: "",
      abstract: "",
      newsUrl: ""
    };
    // this.newsLatest = this.newsLatest.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevProps.newsList !== this.props.newsList) {
      const { newsList } = this.props;
      let maxTime = newsList.map(function(o) {
        return new Date(o.updated_date);
      });
      let maximumValue = Math.max(...maxTime);
      let latestnews = newsList.filter(function(el) {
        return maximumValue === new Date(el.updated_date).getTime();
      })[0];
      this.setState({ newsTitle: latestnews.title });
    }
  }

  // newsLatest = e => {
  //   // e.preventDefault();
  //   const { newsList } = this.props;
  //   let maxTime = newsList.map(function(o) {
  //     return new Date(o.updated_date);
  //   });
  //   let maximumValue = Math.max(...maxTime);
  //   let latestnews = newsList.filter(function(el) {
  //     return maximumValue === new Date(el.updated_date).getTime();
  //   })[0];
  //   console.log(latestnews)
  //   if (latestnews && latestnews.hasOwnProperty('length') && latestnews.length>0) {
  //     return <h4>{this.state.newsTitle}</h4>;
  //   }
  // };
  newsTitle = () =>
    this.props.newsList.map(item => <h2 key={item.title}>{item.title}</h2>);
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.newsList);
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>News Latest....</h2>
        <h4>{this.state.newsTitle}</h4>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default NewsLatest;
```

**Also, a sandbox:** https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-frog-z37y0?fontsize=14

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. It helped me a lot.

Comment: @kabeerSingh mark it as the correct answer if it helped you, might help future readers.